# Color points on a plot according to a vector in Octave

Tags: matlab, plot, octave

I want to plot multiple 2d-points which are stored in a *N*-by-*3* matrix. The first 2 columns define the x and y coordinate. The 3rd column defines the index of the color to be used for a single point and refers to an a list of color codes like this one:

```
c={[1 0 0], [0 1 0], [0 0 1]}
```

I then call the plot function:

```
plot(points(:,1), points(:,2), '.', 'Color', c(points(:,3)));
```

But I only get the error:

> invalid value for color property "color"

Is there any way to plot the points with the according color of each point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`scatter`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html) for this instead of plot:

```
%// Making dummy data:
n = 10;
points = rand(n,2);
points(:,3) = randi(3,n,1);

%//Setting a colormap: note that you should not use a cell array for this!
c=[1 0 0; 0 1 0; 0 0 1]
colormap(c)

%//plot
scatter(points(:,1), points(:,2), [], points(:,3))
```